# Integrating a custom function in Django

Tags: python, django, opendap

I would like to access and print metadata (attributes and values) served by an [ERDDAP](https://gliders.ioos.us/erddap/) server, which is a variety of OPeNDAP, on my Django website.

so I prepared a simple example function called `get_conventions` to access a metadata field on this public server hosting data and metadata. To get started, I install the required packages:

```sh
$ pip install pandas erddapy
```

and then,

```py
import pandas as pd
from erddapy import ERDDAP

def get_conventions(dataset_id):
    e = ERDDAP(server='https://gliders.ioos.us/erddap/', protocol='tabledap', response='csv')
    url = e.get_info_url(dataset_id, response='csv')
    df = pd.read_csv(url)

    # this replace spaces with underscores in column names
    df.columns = [col_name.replace(' ', '_') for col_name in df.columns]

    conventions = df[df.Attribute_Name == 'Conventions'].Value
    return conventions
```

Using a Python interpreter, one could call the function like this with this sample dataset id as an argument (amelia-20180501T0000), which is found on [the server](https://gliders.ioos.us/erddap/tabledap/amelia-20180501T0000.html); the output follows:

```py
>>> get_conventions('amelia-20180501T0000')
6    Unidata Dataset Discovery v1.0, COARDS, CF-1.6
Name: Value, dtype: object
>>>
```

I would like my website to print on a webpage the output of the above function.

I can print the argument string in a page (model.py, views.py and a related html templates - those being similar to the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial03/)), but I am unsure how to refer the argument to the function (and expect a return) or how/where to integrate the function in the Django structure.

The argument is stored in a local database which can be referred using models/views/template

**But I am unsure how to integrate the part involving the function in Django?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make this work after reading [this, by D. Patel](https://medium.com/swlh/custom-functions-in-django-template-tags-64b73037f2a6).

It involved adding the following to the file named `services.py` which was placed an app subfolder titled `templatetags`. This is where the `get_conventions` custom function reside:

```py
from django import template
...

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def get_conventions(dataset_id):
...
    return conventions
```

and in the template, I had to load the `services` file and add the following to the html template:

```py
{% load services %}
{% block content %}
    <p><strong>Conventions:</strong> {{ station.dataset_id | get_conventions }}</p>
...
{% endblock %}
```

`station.dataset_id` being the argument for the get_conventions function paired `|` with the return value

and it worked as intended. It was quite straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

The approach is going to depend on whether the function is going to be used cross-app, in a single app, or is tied to a Django model.

For cross-app functions, I typically create a separate app called core or utils with python files for each set of functionality. For the sake of your example let's call it `erddapy.py`. In the `views.py` that your view is in, simply `from utils.erddapy import get_conventions` and call it in your view passing in the argument. Then return the result as context to the template.

If it's only being used in a single app but not tied to a model you can also create a utils.py file in that app and instead do `from .utils import get_conventions` in your `views.py` then call it in your view.

If you've defined a model for the datasets and store the dataset id there it's probably better suited for a model method. That way you can use the queryset API in your view to get the instance then simply call `instance.get_conventions()`. You wouldn't need an argument for this approach since you could simply get the dataset id from `self.dataset_id` in the method logic.

```
# view
id = self.kwargs.get('id')
if id:
    instance = get_object_or_404(MyModel, id=id)
    data = instance.get_conventions()
# return the data as context in an http response

# model method
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # model fields
    
    def get_conventions(self):
        dataset_id = self.dataset_id
        # get the data
```

I guess the underlying question is how are you storing or obtaining the dataset id? If it's in a separate local database you may need to query it to get the dataset id which I would do in a separate function. Then either pass it into the function as an argument or store it in your Django db as a model instance and use the method approach explained above.

Comment: These are great suggestions - I will try this - will update with results